# What are the default username and password for ubuntu-20.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso?

Tags: server, ssh, login, password, username

I downloaded the ubuntu-20.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso file and installed it into the Oracle cloud virtual server by attaching the boot volume. There was no prompt for username and login password during the installation process, so now I don’t know its ssh Login username and password. Where can I find it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu install process generally prompts you for a user and password. By default root is a random password that protects the system from unauthorised access.

If you want to get into the installation, use the Live cd again.  Once it loads, press ctrl+alt+F3 this is get you a shell.  run "sudo bash" this will give you a root shell.  then mount the installation root, and go to etc, the passwd file will have the user name. To change the password you will need to chroot to the installation root. eg: assuming the installation is on /dev/sda1

```
mkdir /mnt/chroot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/chroot
TARGETDIR="/mnt/chroot"
mount -t proc proc $TARGETDIR/proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs $TARGETDIR/sys
mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs $TARGETDIR/dev
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs $TARGETDIR/dev/shm
mount -t devpts devpts $TARGETDIR/dev/pts
chroot $TARGETDIR /bin/bash
cat /etc/passwd
```

The output will be something like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
<username>:x:1000:1000:Your Name if Entered:/home/<username>:/bin/bash
```

now you have the username, run `passwd <username>` to reset the passwd

You can now reboot, and load the os the normal way, and login.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I reinstalled according to your procedure, but when I pressed ctrl+alt+f3 to install a new ubuntu in the sdb area of ​​the attached instance, the shell did not appear. Therefore, I still cannot set the user name and login password.

Comment: On the first screen for the install, press ctrl-alt-f3-6 all of these shouyld give you a differnt console, if it is not, then the remote console might not be passing through the special keys.  Alternatively, does your live cd have the option to try ubuntu, that will also give you a shell, and the same command apply.

Comment: I attached the boot volume of the original instance to another instance, converted the original iso file into a gz file, and then used a script to install it on the SSH terminal of this instance. After completion, I mounted the boot volume back to the original instance. Maybe the shell interface will not appear during this installation process?